# Calling another function by adding it to a parameter

Tags: java, function, parameter-passing

I was wondering if it's possible to call another function just by adding the function name to the parameter. So for instance I want to make a script with 4 parts. Each part requires input (I am using a scanner, dont ask why :P its the assignment) and then needs to pass it to another script for e.g. calculations and stuff.

I start of with this:

```
static int intKiezer(String returnFunctie, String text) {

    Scanner vrager = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {

        System.out.println(text);
        int intGekozen = vrager.nextInt();

        if (vrager.hasNextInt()) {

            returnFunctie(intGekozen);
        }

        else {

            vrager.next();
            System.out.println("Verkeerde invoer!");
        }
    }
```

As you see I am trying to push the obtained value to another function by trying to call it (returnFunctie(intgekozen)). It should be calling returnFunctie with intgekozen as parameter. But its not working

I would be calling the function like this: `intKiezer(sphereCalculations, "What radius do you want to have?")`. So the answer from the input, if its correct should be passed to another function called sphereCalculations

Comment: Where is your returnFunctie(...) in code?

Comment: This is in principle possible with reflection, but the real question is: why do you want to do this? This is a sign that your program has a strange design. (Reflection should only be used for special cases, I don't want to learn you bad habits).

Comment: The thing is I have multiple inputs and I want to make one function for them all. Not just stating in every function the scanner classe e.g. This seemed for me the easiest way since I only have to add a text and a function name

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea.

Define an interface that has a method that does whatever calculation you want to perform. For example:

```
interface Algorithm {
    int execute(int value);
}
```

Then define one or more classes that implement the interface and do whatever calculations you want them to do. For example:

```
class MultiplyByTwo implements Algorithm {
    public int execute(int value) {
        return value * 2;
    }
}

class AddThree implements Algorithm {
    public int execute(int value) {
        return value + 3;
    }
}
```

Then, write your method so that it accepts an `Algorithm` as a parameter. Execute the algorithm with the desired value.

```
static int intKiezer(Algorithm algo, String text) {
    // ...

    return algo.execute(intGekozen);
}
```

Call your method by passing in an instance of one of the implementation classes of interface `Algorithm`.

```
int result = intKiezer(new MultiplyByTwo(), "Some question");
System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

Comment: Okay I get the point :). The only thing is I am not using classes yet. However I tried editing my script with the trick you told me. I dont know if I am aplying it correctly. Shouldnt it be working by only adding return "returnFunctie.execute(intGekozen);"

Comment: +1 You can even une anonymous implementation if you don't want to have too many classes

Answer (score 1):

As @Jesper said, it is possible with reflection, and probably only with reflection. Reflection is the process in which an object can analyze itself and iterate through it's members (attributes and methods). In your case, it seems you are looking for a method.

By the looks of your code, it seems like what you want is, in fact, passing a function object to your code, where a parameter could be applied. This isn't possible in Java. Something similar will be possible in Java 8 with the addition of closures. You could do that in Groovy, by passing a Closure as a parameter, or other language with support for closure or functions.

You can get near what you want by defining an abstract class/interface, passing an instance of it to your method, and then calling a method passing the parameter to it, like:

```
interface Function <T> {
  public Integer call(T t);
}


public class TestFunction {
    static int intKiezer(Function<Integer> returnFunctie, String text) 
    {
        int a = 10;
        System.out.println(text);

        return returnFunctie.call(a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Function<Integer> function = new Function<Integer>() {
          public Integer call(Integer t) { return t * 2; }
        };

        System.out.println( intKiezer(function, "Applying 10 on function") );
    }
}
```

If your intention is to call a method, then you are better using some reflection library. [Apache Common's MethodUtil](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/reflect/MethodUtils.html) comes to mind. I think this your man:

```
invokeMethod(Object object, String methodName, Object arg)
    Invoke a named method whose parameter type matches the object type.
```